# When is it wrong to not do a positive mitzvah

Tags: mitzvah, reward-punishment

I've heard several times in the past (without sources) that it is a big problem for a Jewish man to not wear tzitzis during the day, but why?  Isn't it just that we are rewarded for doing it?  Does this apply to all mitzvahs?  If so, how can we function without driving ourselves mad by constantly having to do mitzvahs that we have the opportunity to do?

EDIT: Another example to clarify.  I walked past a blood drive yesterday and felt bad for not giving blood, because it could save someone's life and therefore be Pikuach Nefesh.  I think it would have been a mitzva had I done that, but does that mean I was obligated to?  I think this is perhaps a better example because it is not clearly obligatory, but it is quite a significant thing, being (sofek) Pikuach Nefesh?  (and even sofek Pikuach Nefesh is enough for us to break Shabbos)

Comment: possible duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/12366/759

Comment: If you are commanded to file your taxes, doesn't that mean you have to do it? I'm not sure what you're finding confusing about the general case of "commandment"

Comment: @DoubleAA So you are saying we're expected to do every positive mitzvah that we have an opportunity to do?

Comment: Is your question about tzitzis specifically or about all positive mitvzvos? I ask because morning and being a male happens to you wether you like it or not, and so you are obligated in various mitzvos. Whereas tzitzis is stated as, if your wearing a 4 cornered garment then add tzitzis. Not necessarily implying you must wear a 4 cornered garment.

Comment: Sorry, tzitzis is just an example

Comment: DoubleAA's reference points out that tzitzis is a confusing example, and in fact I can't tell whether the OP understands that. Does he consider tzitzis to be like "filing your taxes", completely required, or is he asking about doing the mitzvah when one could avoid the issue by not wearing a four-cornered garment?

Comment: @MosesSupposes If so, would you ask the same question about lulav and esrog? That is completely required, and no one would say about it, "Isn't it just that we are rewarded..." No. We were ordered to do it by G-d in the Torah.

Comment: I've tried to clarify my question a bit

Comment: You were right for feeling bad. You should give blood more often. (I don't actually know you so maybe you have some excuse but the vast majority of people in the world should give blood more often.)

Comment: I think the issue is that it is perceived as such an easy mitzva to do and that one (supposedly) gets constant schar for, so therefore not doing it shows significant disregard.

Comment: There is a difference between having an opportunity to become obligated in a mitzvah, and doing the mitzvah one your already obligated. Buying a four cornered garment, looking for a birds nest for shiluach hakan, buying a field to be able to bring Bikkurim, etc. are all cases where a person is putting himself in a situation that will then make him obligated. He doesn’t have to do that, it’s recommended but not obligated. However once he owned a four cornered garment, or a field, or found a birds nest AC he wants the eggs, then he’s obligated to do the mitzvah.

Comment: Same with chesed and tzedaka. If someone approaches you and requests help, or you pass them by and they need help and there’s nobody else helping, then you’re obligated to help to the best of your ability. Going out to search for such opportunities is a tremendous zechus (rodef tzedaka and chesed) but it’s not an obligation in the full sense of the word. Passing by a blood drive that is a general drive to fill a blood bank, may not be an obligation per se, but is surely a very nice thing to do.

Comment: @DoubleAA It is on the list of what feels like a few thousand things that I should do!  I had a meeting with my Rav booked which I was going to at the time, so I couldn't actually (it was actually going on in my shul), but I don't think I would do it that close to Yom Kippur anyway.

Comment: @ASL So you are saying that is quite specific to tzitzis then?

Comment: @Chatzkel I'm thinking about this and I'm not sure that there is always such a clear distinction?  Perhaps it boils down to just being about learning Torah, as that is the only thing that springs to mind that you can pretty much do most of the time.

Comment: Torah actually is an obligation for every free minute. You are always in that situation. But that’s a whole different discussion. Shaking lulav, shofar, fasting on YK, etc are all mitzvohs that you are obligated once you are in the situation, which in these instances, is based on time. Before the time, you are not obligated. (Obviously, one can’t move time to become obligated, so it isn’t relevant to our discussion)

Comment: @Moses so schedule an appointment for your next available timeslot. Balancing thousands of obligations is all about planning. No different then everything else we do in life (work, kids, meals, shopping, etc.)

Comment: @DoubleAA I don't remember the last time I felt that I had a free timeslot!  Probably a few years ago!

Answer (score 2):

This is an excellent topic and question. You have partially given us an answer by acknowledging, in your first sentence, that you do not have a source for this being a problem.

Within Orthodox communities, and communities in general, there is pressure to adhere to a status norm. This can be healthy (or unhealthy) depending on the delivery, tone, circumstances, and the individual.

It is a big problem for a Jewish man not to wear tzitzit in the same sense that it is a big problem for a Jewish man not to keep the Torah and all of its written and oral laws.

The reason for this is a huge series of rewards and punishments - but to go into those details somewhat circumvents the main point. Which is this: G-d gave us the Torah as an instruction manual on how to live life. Thank G-d that we have this guide and the opportunity to live an extremely moral and meaningful existence based on the Torah's teachings.

If someone were to give you an incredible gift, and you were to not use that gift, or to let it sit in the closet, that person would be somewhat sad that you did not take advantage of what they have given you. This is an interesting analogy, but consider how much more significant the Torah is than any human gift. It is Divine. It is literally our source of life. When we decide between following the Torah and not, it it literally deciding between life and death, as stated in Deuteronomy 30:19

> I have put before you life and death, blessing and curse. Choose life - and you and your offspring would live - by loving the Lord your God, heeding His commands, and holding fast to Him.

This is not to pressure you into following every set law. Everyone is constantly growing on their own path, at their own pace, over a very long period of time. We spend our entire lives studying the Torah, and more so.

We can function by understanding that G-d loves us and has put us into a specific point in time with unique skills. We are not here to perfect the world, but neither are we here to neglect it. May your journey be joyful and filled with blessings.